# Где в файловом менеджере для сайта на базе WordPress можно поменять логин и пароль от админки сайта?

Tags: wordpress

Где в файловом менеджере для сайта на базе WordPress можно поменять логин и пароль от админки сайта?

Answer (score 0):

Пароль хранится в БД, он хеширован. Вот [способы замены](https://wpmag.ru/2013/izmenit-parol-v-wordpress/). Заходите на вашу БД, например, с помощью phpMyAdmin и находите таблицу `wp_users` - в ней содержится список всех пользователей. Находите себя и нажимаете редактировать. В поле `user_pass` вписуете пароль и хешируете его в `md5` (`function -> md5`). И сохраняете.

Comment: Круто , спасибо ))

Comment: @СторчакаЮрий Если ответ помог - стоит отметить его решенным.